# iOS: displaying text of NSArray with "("

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have the `ItemSore.m`:

```
-(instancetype)initPrivate
{
    NSArray *operatorUS = @[@"AT&T", @"Verizion"];
    NSArray *operatorRU = @[@"MTS", @"Megafon"];
    NSArray *operatorFR = @[@"Orange", @"SFR"];
    NSArray *operatorAE = @[@"Etisalat", @"Du"];
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _privateItems = @{@"USA":operatorUS, @"Russia":operatorRU, @"France":operatorFR, @"UAE":operatorAE};
    }
    return self;
}
```

declared method:

```
-(NSArray *)allProviders
{
    return [self.privateItems allValues];
}
```

In my `ItemsViewController` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` I pass the value to pushViewController like this:

```
NSArray *items = [[MSTItemStore sharedStore] allProviders];
MSTItemStore *selectedItem = items[indexPath.row];
providerViewController.item = selectedItem;
```

In `providerViewController` (pushViewController) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I try to get it like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_item description]];
```

But in cell i get only "(" and no text. What is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: What was your desired output ?

Comment: Try to `NSLog` `[_item description]`. Maybe the first line is "(" and your label is set to display only 1 line. Try setting its `lineNumber` property to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your `_item` is an `NSArray` (one of the operators being selected on the first controller). So assuming that you want to get the operator names and display it in your cells,  and provided that `_item` is the datasource array, you should be doing something like this instead:

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.item[indexPath.row];
```

**EDIT** (After OP's comment regarding `indexPath.row`)

> what does really mean this self.item[indexPath.row]?

Well, let's have a look at your `item` here. Let's assume that you have selected `operatorUS` on the first controller. Your `item` in your second controller is something like this:

```
(
    "AT&T", // <= index 0
    Verizion // <= index 1
)
```

Now, your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method should look like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.item.count;
}
```

Which states that 'For section `x` I have `n` rows'. Since you only got one section, you just count the operators contained in your `item` and return it.

Finally, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the `indexPath` (an object that specifies a given row of a section) is passed to you and you return a cell configured based on this indexPath, where `indexPath.row` is the index of the row that corresponds to the `indexPath.section` (again, you have just one section). So eventually the method will be called 2 times (`self.item.count`) and `indexPath.row` will be `0` and `1`. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: If I use 'cell.textLabel.text = self.item[indexPath.row];' it gives me an error like this '-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]' '

Comment: and if i use `cell.textLabel.text = self.item[0];` it returns me only first item, although I need all of items

Comment: @user3684151: Check the numberOfRowInSection method.

Comment: OK we will need a little more information here. Can you post your datasource methods? (`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` etc)

Comment: @MidhunMP and Alladinian the numberOfRowInSection really helped me! but can you please give me a little more information about indexPath.row, I mean what does really mean this self.item[indexPath.row]? Thanks!

Comment: i think he need section for each array object here.

Comment: 'self.item[indexPath.row]'  means [self.item objectAtIndex:index.row]. @user3684151

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *firstString = items[indexPath.row][0];
NSString *secondString = items[indexPath.row][1];
```

Answer (score -1):

That because your _item it is array. Inside _item you have array of your operator`s. Ex. if you do

```
items[indexPath.row];
```

For cell 0 you have an array of operatorUS. Then you should do something like this:

```
cell.textLabel1.text = self.items[0]; //return AT&T
cell.textLabel2.text = self.items[1]; //return Verizion
```

Comment: Yeah< u r right, but how I can get the items from that array?